# MySQL table.column doesn`t update

Tags: mysql

It's actually happening in a production system (wasn't in development, neither in production tests).

I have `students.motherCPF/fatherCPF` both int(11) and default is NULL, students table engine is `InnoDB`, and it actually has 132 rows.

The value is primarily NULL then is updated to the one sent thought HTML Form and passing throught treatments in PHP. This happens when registering a student. The update query has already been dumped and the values are being passed correctly.

The thing is: In the DB, the values are wrong. In some rows they appear as 2147483647, in other as another numbers, and they are all wrong.
CPF in Brazil stands for Personal Registry Number, which is an 11 digit num that is like an ID, so it's unique and personal.
I've seen 2147483647 in more than 10 rows, and it`s always equal in motherCPF and fatherCPF columns.

I've already tried updating directly through PHPMyAdmin, through the PHP system, and nothing happens. No errors, 0 rows affected, and no changes.
The DB user is root and has the needed privileges.
I only didn`t drop the table and created again, because there are already 132 rows in it.

Does someone know what is happening?

The database is all fine, only these 2 columns gone mad.

Comment: `2147483647` is the maximum for signed 32 bit integers. Is the column signed or unsigned?

Comment: the general misinterpretation of `int(11)` that the max is `99999999999` which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL the `INT(11)` specifier means that it's formatted as if it has 11 places, but it doesn't have the ability to store 11 arbitrary digits. In fact you're hitting the [limit of a signed value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

Switching to `BIGINT` may side-step this problem, but for "numbers" like this you may want to use something else, like `VARCHAR(255)`. Only use numerical fields for numbers you'd actually compute on, like amounts, years, prices, that sort of thing. For "numerical identifiers", or identifiers that just happen to be all digits, you may want to stick with `VARCHAR` to avoid issues exactly like this.

It may be 11 digits today, but then unexpectedly due to some new bureaucratic rule it becomes 12 tomorrow, or maybe 14 digits plus two letters for reasons you can't even fathom. You don't want your app to make too many assumptions about the future.

Comment: *"In MySQL the INT(11) specifier means that it's formatted as if it has 11 places,"* `INT(11)` only makes (some) sense with used together with [ZEROFILL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) option

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well, it has other implications, but it's mostly cosmetic. `INT(1)` can still store the same values as `INT(11)`, while `VARCHAR(1)` truncates. Not sure why this is, MySQL seems very quirky here.

Comment: *"Well, it has other implications, but it's mostly cosmetic. INT(1) can still store the same values as INT(11), while VARCHAR(1)  truncates. Not sure why this is, MySQL seems very quirky here"* Indeed like i said in the question comments section *"the general misinterpretation of int(11) that the max is 99999999999 which is not true. "*  Also not sure why you mention in `VARCHAR` datatype after it mentioned `ZEROFILL` option because that will not work on those datatypes it wil only work on integer data types

Comment: @RaymondNijland You wouldn't want zerofill in this case, that might screw up the data.

Comment: *"You wouldn't want zerofill in this case, that might screw up the data."* i never used it and i never will, best advice also for everybody else

Comment: @RaymondNijland Can't argue with that.